# Assign one of values in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Post model has two fields: title and category_id. In simple_form I'd like to assign name and it's ok, but category I'd like to assign in controller (value will be different dependends on action). But I have problem, because every time category_id is null.
I just do:

```
 def fun
  @post=Post.new
  @post.category_id=1
 end
```

it doesn't work and

```
  @post=Post.new(category_id: 1)
```

too.

```
 <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :posts
end
```

Comment: please tell the association...

Comment: after assigning the category you have to save @post, then pass it forward, then load it again in the controller that you POST the form to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what @OscillatingMonkey suggested, but I would strongly suggest to use a hidden field tag in your `new` form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id, value: @post.category_id %>
```

In that case your controller `new` would be:

```
@post = Post.new(category_id: 1)
```

Calling `save` in `new` action is a terrible thing, AFAIK. Every time the `new` action is called, a new object will be created irrespective the user continued or not. So I would prefer using hidden field over calling `save` method on `new`.

Comment: Could you mentioned like my controller should be then?

Comment: `@post = Post.new(category_id: 1)`

Comment: It works but when I write <%= f.hidden_field :category_id, value: 1 %> when I use params is null

Comment: Can you try with `f.hidden_field :category_id, value: params[:category_id]` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work but <%= f.hidden_field :category_id, value: @post.category_id %> is ok! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun
  @post=Post.new
  @post.category_id=1
  @post.save
end
```

After POSTing the form, load it and save the values to it (or update). The form itself is not passing the value of @post into your next controller. If you don't intend on post existing if the user does not enter any information in then only create it in the controller that your form POSTs to. I am mentioning this assuming that the reason you want to set the category_id is because you want it to exist when you save the @post object in the next controller action.